# Project files for Cern Root framework

Tags: c++, cmake, root-framework

I don't know anything about CMake.
Can someone provide a simple and straightforward step-by-step guide on 
how to obtain the project files (Visual Studio 2010 or 2013) for the
root-cern framework (version 6.06/02) on Windows 10?
I already have CMake installed (version 3.4.1, default installation).
My library path is `D:\cpp\cern\root.`
Inside the root directory there is a `CMakeLists.txt` file and so in many subdirectories.
Is it easier to use CMake in console or GUI version?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I your case, i guess, GUI version would fit better.

Comment: I haven't ever tried this, but maybe the instructions at http://www.opentissue.org/mediawiki/index.php/Using_CMake would help? Good luck!

Comment: distinguish two things. Building root with cmake (what the `CMakeLists.txt` in the root git repository are good for) and building your own project which depends on root. For the latter, there is the `cmake` subdirectory in your root installation (`ROOTConfig.cmake` and others). These are the ones CMake needs to find to build your project. (And from here on, a good CMake instruction - not neccessarily specific to root - should help.

Comment: See https://root.cern/blog/code-horsepower-f1/ https://root.cern/blog/debuging-root-scripts-in-eclipse/ and https://root.cern/blog/root-on-vscode/